# Flipping Rotations and Images

Tags: java, rotation, position

I'm programming a platform game in Java, and I am hand-coding the player animations. I am animating each limb separately, changing the position and rotation. This works fine when the player is facing right, but when the player faces left, I don't know how to deal with the rotations to make them look the same when the player turns left. Each body part's location is stored relative to the player's x and y values, so really I need a way to flip rotations horizontally. I know I'm not explaining this very well, but if someone understands what I'm trying to say and can help, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Calculate the rotations per normal (facing right), then try scaling the image in a negative direction (`-1`), this will invert/mirror the image

Comment: I am only drawing things to the screen so that they look rotated, the image files themselves are not rotated, so scaling in a negative direction won't work. (I believe)

Comment: Create a temporary instance of the `Graphics` context, apply your rotation and scaling within it...

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `Graphics#create`, just don't forget to `dispose` of it when you finished.  This will allow you to make changes to this "copy" of the `Graphics` without affecting the base `Graphics` context

Answer (score 2):

So the basic idea is to simply flip/mirror the `Graphics` context by scaling one of the axis by a negative value (`-1`).

This can be accomplished by simply using `Graphics#scale`, for example, to flip the graphics horizontally, you would simply use

```
graphics.scale(-1, 1);
```

You would need to translate the `Graphics` by the width of the viewable area as well using `Graphics#translate` to reposition the image within the viewable area.

Everything painted after this will be affected by the change.  Because of this, you should be taking snapshots of the `Graphics` context before every significant change, just make sure you `dispose` of it when you're done...

Here is a (rather pathetic animation wise) example...Basically, when you press the left or right arrows, a flag is flipped and the scene repainted.  Depending on the flag, the `Graphics` context is flipped/mirrored...

[image: Pony Run]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class AnimateCharacter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnimateCharacter();
    }

    public AnimateCharacter() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage body;
        private BufferedImage[] legs;

        private double[] angels;
        private double[] deltas;

        private Point[] pivots = new Point[]{
            // Foreground...
            new Point(100, 227), // Foreleg
            new Point(155, 201), // Hindleg
            // Background...
            new Point(93, 218), // Foreleg
            new Point(143, 195), // Hindleg
        };

        private Point[] locations = new Point[]{
            // Foreground...
            new Point(67, 221), // Foreleg
            new Point(124, 172), // Hindleg
            // Background...
            new Point(60, 219), // Foreleg
            new Point(112, 166), // Hindleg
        };

        private int direction = 1;

        public TestPane() {
            legs = new BufferedImage[4];
            angels = new double[]{
                45,
                40,
                -5,
                0
            };
            deltas = new double[]{
                -4,
                -4,
                4,
                4
            };
            try {
                body = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Body.png"));
                // Foreground...
                legs[0] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/ForeLeg.png"));
                legs[1] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/HindLeg.png"));
                // Background...
                legs[2] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/ForeLeg.png"));
                legs[3] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/HindLeg.png"));
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < angels.length; index++) {
                        angels[index] += deltas[index];
                        if (angels[index] < -45) {
                            angels[index] = -45;
                            deltas[index] *= -1;
                        } else if (angels[index] > 45) {
                            angels[index] = 45;
                            deltas[index] *= -1;
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");

            am.put("left", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    direction = 1;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            am.put("right", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    direction = -1;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return body == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(body.getWidth() + 50, body.getHeight() + 50);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            applyQualityRenderingHints(g2d);

            int x = (getWidth() - body.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - body.getHeight()) / 2;

            if (direction < 0) {
                g2d.scale(-1, 1);
                g2d.translate(-getWidth(), 0);
            }

            // Background legs...
            drawLegs(g2d, x, y, 2);

            g2d.drawImage(body, x, y, this);

            // Foreground legs...
            drawLegs(g2d, x, y, 0);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void drawLegs(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y, int offset) {

            for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
                Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
                copy.translate(x, y);
                int leg = index + offset;
                int pivotX = pivots[leg].x;
                int pivotY = pivots[leg].y;
                copy.rotate(Math.toRadians(angels[leg]), pivotX, pivotY);
                copy.drawImage(
                        legs[leg],
                        locations[leg].x,
                        locations[leg].y,
                        this);
                copy.dispose();
            }

        }

        public void applyQualityRenderingHints(Graphics2D g2d) {

            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
//        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        }
    }

}
```

The magic happens in a few places...

The `Graphics` context is first copied and then (if required) flipped using `scale`...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    //...
    if (direction < 0) {
        g2d.scale(-1, 1);
        g2d.translate(-getWidth(), 0);
    }
```

I also use the same technique when painting the legs...

```
protected void drawLegs(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y, int offset) {

    for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
        Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        copy.translate(x, y);
        //...
        copy.rotate(Math.toRadians(angels[leg]), pivotX, pivotY);
        copy.drawImage(
                legs[leg],
                locations[leg].x,
                locations[leg].y,
                this);
        copy.dispose();
    }
```

This isolates the changes to the copy of the `Graphics` context, each copy will inherit the current state of it's parent, making this a really useful technique...