# Reversing an image about axis or draw a reversed one to use instead?

Tags: java

I am working on a java game which deals with a bunch of sprite sheets, and I was wondering whether I should have separate sprite sheets for left and right animations, or if I should just draw up the left sprites and reverse the image programatically for the right animations. Which one would be a better practice, and would either of them perform better? I was thinking of having the image flipping occur during Game init(). If I do go with direction flipping (saving a lot of time in photoshop), would this be a safe way to go:

```
        playerAttackLeft = spriteSheet.crop(0, 0, 400, 400);  //(x, y, width, height)
        playerAttackRight = spriteSheet.crop(400, 0, -400, 400);
```

?

Comment: You tried? Throws exception?

Comment: Basically you're asking to mirror the image, you can do this by scaling one of the axis by -1

Comment: Take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522458/flipping-rotations-and-images/24523176#24523176)

Comment: My code snippet in the main question worked, I was just wondering if this was the ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `rotate the image` and use it instead of getting new one.
When you read an image then it will take space for JVM to load it.

Here is an example when I did it on my computer.
I had an image of 100kb and when I loaded it in my `class`, It has taken approximately 1mb of space.

`reading an image is costly process`


And on the other hand if you will use rotated image it will not only save your space but also your time too (space and time complexity, both) because rotating image will take much less time then to read an external image.