# How to rotate one object in graphics java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, shapes, bluej

I have the following code. The one problem is that I wanted to rotate only one part of the of my program (drawBody). But, the rotate code I used is turning every shape in my program. How can I just rotate one shape in the graphics java

This is the program:

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    BlueJ.drawBody(g);
    BlueJ.drawBody(g);
    BlueJ.drawHead(g);
    BlueJ.drawFace(g);
    BlueJ.drawTail(g);
    BlueJ.drawWings(g);
    BlueJ.drawLegs(g);

}
```

class BlueJ

```
public static void drawHead(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawOval(20,100,90,90);
}

public static void drawTail(Graphics g)
{        
}

public static void drawFace(Graphics g)
{
    //=============Nose=====================//

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    Polygon nose = new Polygon();

    nose.addPoint(60,160);
    nose.addPoint(40,200);
    nose.addPoint(80,150);
    g.drawPolygon(nose);
    g.fillPolygon(nose);

    //==============Eye======================//
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillOval(45,140,15,15);


}


public static void drawBody(Graphics g)
{


    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform oldTransform = g2d.getTransform();

    RoundRectangle2D roundedRectangle = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(100, 110, 190, 110, 500, 500);
    g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 4, 270, 620));
    g2d.draw(roundedRectangle);

    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 400, 150, 150);

    Shape rotatedRect = at.createTransformedShape(roundedRectangle);



}


public static void drawWings(Graphics g)
{
}

public static void drawLegs(Graphics g)
{
}
```

}

Comment: You need to create a copy of the `Graphics` context (`Graphics#create`) and make you translations within the copy.  When you're done, don't forget to dispose of the copy `(Graphics#dispose`), [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522458/flipping-rotations-and-images/24523176#24523176)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the same Graphics object `g` to each of the methods.  That means any time you call `drawBody(g)`, it will rotate the entire object.

If you want to only apply the rotation to a single method, consider creating a new object, rotating, and then adding that resultant object to the original object.

Comment: I think you mean something `g.create()`?

Comment: Creating a `new` `Graphics` `Object` is tedious, try it. :) I'd go with @MadProgrammer and copy it.

Comment: I still don't understand, what I am supposed to do? Create a new object? And How am I supposed to use g.create() in the program?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Graphics#create` to create a copy of the `Graphics` context.  This simply provides you a copy of the current state of the `Graphics` context, it still paints to the same output, but what it does is allows you to change the properties of the copy without affecting the original, for example...

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics copy = g.create();
    BlueJ.drawBody(copy);
    copy.dispose();
    copy = g.create();
    BlueJ.drawBody(copy);
    copy.dispose();
    copy = g.create();
    BlueJ.drawHead(copy);
    copy.dispose();
    copy = g.create();
    BlueJ.drawFace(copy);
    copy.dispose();
    copy = g.create();
    BlueJ.drawTail(copy);
    copy.dispose();
    copy = g.create();
    BlueJ.drawWings(copy);
    copy.dispose();
    copy = g.create();
    BlueJ.drawLegs(copy);
    copy.dispose();
}
```

The other choice is to reverse the transformations, but frankly, this is simpler.

My general practice is to always create a snapshot/copy of a `Graphics` context before I manipulate it, that would mean having your `drawXxx` methods make the copy.  The example above is more of a pessimistic approach, meaning I don't trust the `drawXxx` methods to do the right thing