# How to move oval and rectangle in the same position when using keypress

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to move oval and rectangle on the same position. However when I'm pressing left arrow and up arrow the oval is in the wrong place. Can anyone please help me on this.

[image: pacman1]
[image: pacman]

```
         int keyboardPress = keyboard.getKeyCode();
         if(keyboardPress == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
             xLocation += 30;
             xLocationEyes += 30;
             angle = 45;
             repaint();
         }
         else if(keyboardPress == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
             if(xLocation == xrandomLocation + 40){

             }
             angle = -145;
             xLocation -= 30;
             xLocationEyes -= 30;
             repaint();
         }
         else if(keyboardPress == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
             angle = -45;
             yLocation += 30;
             yLocationEyes += 30;
             repaint();
         }
         else if(keyboardPress == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
             angle = -235;
             yLocation -= 30;
             yLocationEyes -= 30;
             repaint();
         }
```

Comment: Use an `AffineTransform` to invert the `Graphics`

Comment: As demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522458/flipping-rotations-and-images/24523176#24523176)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).