# Trying to use actionListener to turn a String upside down

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint

From my textbook:
"Write an application that extends JFrame and that displays a phrase upside down when the user click a button. The phrase is displayed normally when the user clicks the button again."

Currently I have a String that is drawn using the paint() method and a Graphic object. The String is visible in the JUpsideDown frame and it's upside down and positioned in about the middle of the panel. I've added my button and a actionListener but I think the code in my actionPerformed method is wrong because I'm trying to make the negative font size a positive by multiplying by -1 but it doesn't seem to take effect when I repaint. The String positioned is moved to x = 100 ad y = 100 but the String is still upside down.

Any kind of guidance is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JUpsideDown extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    int x = 350;
    int y = 100;
    int fontSize = -26;
    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
    JButton press = new JButton("Flip Text");
    String label = "Look at this text, it will flip!";

    public JUpsideDown()
    {
        setTitle("JUpsideDown");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(press);
        press.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(label, x, y);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        fontSize = fontSize * -1;
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JUpsideDown frame = new JUpsideDown();
        frame.setSize(450, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: your font instance wouldn't know when and how you are changing the fontSize variable of the JUpsideDown class....

Comment: I don't think using a negative font size will flip the text, you'd need to scale the `Graphics` context through a negative state instead, which would also require to provide an additional offset to compensate. As general rule, you don't want to override `paint` of top level container like `JFrame`, it can cause no end of issues, instead, you should start with a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead

Comment: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522458/flipping-rotations-and-images/24523176#24523176) demonstrates using a negative scale to flip the `Graphics` context

Comment: Another solution would be to simply rotate the `Graphics` context around the centre of the text instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used a negative font to show the String upside down to begin with. Is there to way to simply alter the textSize variable to a positive by multiplying it inside of the actionPerformed method?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've tried everything that my book has covered so far. I  don't think that it has gone over any of the other options that you have suggested.

Comment: @PStevens Well, that was a surprising and unexpected result, although, for my money, I'd just rotate the `Graphics` context around the centre of the text, but that's me

Comment: @MadProgrammer is there a way to put a paint() or paintComponent() inside of an actionPerformed method()?

Comment: @PStevens No - you just call `repaint` - the key problem you have right now is you're not actually updating the state of the `font`, you're just changing some state variable

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to declare the font variable again inside of the actionPerformed method() but it's then just a local variable then and not seen by the paint() method nor can I set the Graphic object's font inside of the actionPerformed method().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is right, although you need to instantiate again a new `Font` object which will encapsulate the new `fontsize`. This should be performed after the button is clicked inside `actionPerformed()` method. In this way the behavior of the application will be the expected.

Below you may find a possible solution:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        fontSize = fontSize * -1;
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize); //added line
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: `font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize); //added line`
That works and I think I tried something very similar to this but I tried to instantiate a new Font object named "font"

`Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize); //added line`
I think this is what I had before and obviously it wouldn't work because the font object is localized to the actionPerformed method. Thank you!